# Why will A atoms diffuse from β phase to α phase and B atoms from α phase to β phase?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, metallurgy, chemical-engineering

> [image: Molar free energy plot]
>
> At the initial compositions 1 and 2 of $α$ and $β$ respectively the chemical potentials of A and B atoms in each phase can be found by extrapolation of the tangents to the free energy curves at 1 and 2 to the corresponding sides of the free energy diagram, as shown above.
>
> All atoms diffuse so as to reduce their chemical potential.
> Therefore, A atoms will have a tendency to diffuse from $α$ to $β$ $(μ_\ce{A}^α > μ_\ce{A}^β)$ and B atoms will have a tendency to diffuse from $β$ to $α$ $(μ_\ce{B}^β > μ_\ce{B}^α)$

The point marked 1 and 2 are basically the compositions of two metal alloys that have been welded. Now annealing is performed at a particular temperature $T_1$ to bring about the change now why will A atoms diffuse from $\beta$ phase to $\alpha$ phase and B atoms from $\alpha$ phase to $\beta$ phase?

How will drawing a common tangent be different in interpretation than drawing two individual tangents at compositions 1 and 2?

Comment: Maybe i’m missing something, but I don’t see the combined molar fee energy curve on your diagram.

Comment: @ChetMiller This is all that I know.

Comment: @ChetMiller - the dashed line is the common tangent for equilibrium between the phases. OP - the common tangent line, and the tie to chemical potential, as well as the drive to have the same chemical potential for the components in the phases, is likely discussed in your text. If not, find a copy of Porter and Easterling in the library and read the first chapter or two.

Comment: @Jon Custer  I'm not the OP.  But, the part that threw me a little is that each phase has its own total molar free energy curve in the figure.  The two curves have a common tangent at the equilibrium concentration combination.  I'm more used to seeing a single total molar free energy curve for the two species, with 2 minima in the curve, and a common tangent to the two minimum portions of the curves.  The rest of the explanation makes sense to me.

Comment: @ChetMiller Ok ignore what you do not know explain the rest to me.

Comment: What I feel Is you can treat that as a single curve as well.@ChetMiller

Comment: Well, I think you can probably derive the single curve from the two given, but those given have to be weighted properly in terms of the mole fractions to obtain it.

Comment: @ChetMiller - interesting. In the Calphad world, one has free energy curves vs concentration for each phase, then go find the common tangents. Showing it as one curve just means you have reduced it to one ‘hull’, but that doesn’t really help understand what is occurring in various complex systems.

Comment: Phases are basically open systems within a close system isn't it?

Comment: OP - do you understand the connection between the intersection of a tangent to the free energy curve and the free energy of a component in the phase?

Comment: @ChetMiller@Jon Custer Please explain me the rest.

Comment: In response to "OP - do you understand the connection between the intersection of a tangent to the free energy curve and the free energy of a component in the phase?" No I do not understand its significance.Nothing at all.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/19454/boundary-lines-in-phase-diagrams-and-the-lever-rule/19468#19468 Might help.

Comment: @JonCuster What if I had a G vs X curve with two minima at the two extremes and one maxima in between?